# The game object does not have a script attached to it

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

[image] - error message

After completing the bullet script operation, I tried to insert the script into Bullet Sprite in 2D Object format, but an error was displayed and the insertion was not possible. I tried turning off and on the editor because I thought it was a bug because I had the same file name and class name, but it didn't work. Do you happen to know about this problem? The editor version is 2021.3.11f1.

Bullet Script

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Pool;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 10f;

    private IObjectPool<Bullet> pool;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.up);
    }    
    
    public void SetPool(IObjectPool<Bullet> bulletPool)
    {
        Launcher.Instance.bulletPool = pool;
    }

    private void OnBecameInvisible()
    {
        Launcher.Instance.bulletPool.Release(this);
    }

}
```

I turned off and on the editor and changed the class name because I thought it was different.

Comment: Do you have another object with the same nam _and_ namespace. Did you check the cases, don't know is filenames are case-sensitive.

Comment: Please don't use [tag:unityscript] as tag again, it's old and not used by Unity3D itself anymore. The tag for Unity3D is [tag:unity3d]. What's in a name, right?

Comment: OK, thx :) I didn't know much about Tag's rules.